# {} + [] + {} = [object Object][object Object]?

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь разобраться в некоторых тонкостях js. 
`{} + [] = 0` , потому что `{}` будет восприниматься как пустой блок кода, а `+ []` приведется к числу, т.е. к 0, окей.

А почему
`{} + [] + {}  = "[object Object][object Object]"` ?
Ну т.е. я ожидал, что тут будет `0 + {}` и выдаст что-то типа `"0[object Object]"`. Почему так?

Comment: Не минусовал, но мне кажется вопрос слишком абстрактный. У вас есть более конкретный, жизненный пример?

Comment: Не понимаю, за что минусуют. Причём тут жизненные примеры? Человек хочет разобраться в тонкостях языка. Что в этом плохого?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, это от браузера зависит. Как я понимаю, вы это проверяете в Хроме, а там [оборачивается всё, что начинается с `{` и заканчивается `}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438034/why-is-no-longer-nan-in-chrome-console?noredirect=1&lq=1).

В Firefox выводится ожидаемое `"0[object Object]"`.